# Locate Git installation folder on Mac OS X

Tags: git, macos

I'm just curious, Where Git get installed (via DMG) on Mac OS X file system?

Comment: `/usr/local/git/`
`/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core`

Comment: `/usr/bin/git` on OS X 10.9.5 and XCode 6.1

Comment: you can always open up a terminal and type in `whereis git`

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The installer from [the git homepage](http://git-scm.com/) installs into **/usr/local/git** by default. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725389/how-to-get-started-with-git-on-mac/4725627#4725627). However, if you install XCode4, it will install a git version in **/usr/bin**. To ensure you can easily upgrade from the website and use the latest git version, edit either your profile information to place **/usr/local/git/bin** before **/usr/bin** in the **$PATH** or edit **/etc/paths** and insert **/usr/local/git/bin** as the first entry ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364340/does-xcode-4-install-git/5365851#5365851)).

Comment: I first installed git 1.8 via dmg, but then installed the Command Line Tools for XCode (not the full XCode4) from Apple which installed 1.7. Placing /usr/local/git/bin in the front of my path got me using 1.8 again. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, it worked for me too on 10.8.4, had the old version and new installation was not reflecting, changing order in /etc/paths works.

Answer (score 229):

Is it in your PATH?  If so just run `which git` in the terminal and it will tell you.

Comment: this will give the path of the git binary file not the git installation directory.

Comment: If you're trying to sort through multiple `git` installations, `which -a git` will tell you all of them in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 55):

simply type in `which git` in your terminal window and it will show you exactly where it was installed.

Answer (score 22):

you can simply use this command on a terminal to find out git on unix platforms (mac/linux) -

`whereis git` or `which git`

This command should return something like - /usr/bin/git or any other location where git is installed

Answer (score 8):

On most of UNIX based sys, its at **`/usr/bin/git`** (if installed with default options) 
all git related scripts are at **`/usr/libexec/git-core`**

Answer (score 7):

You can also try with `/usr/local/bin/git`  it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Usually some of the applications have been known to take it from the Xcode.app path also:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/

Coda 2, prefers this path than the soft link at /usr/bin.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly in `/usr/local/git` (there are also `/etc/paths.d/git` and `/etc/manpaths.d/git` items).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux the command is whereis. Alternatively you can issue `find / -name git` and wait for an eternity. Alternatively try `echo $PATH  | sed "s/:/ /g" | xargs -L 1 ls | grep git`

Answer (score 0):

If you have fresh installation / update of Xcode, it is possible that your git binary can't be executed (I had mine under `/usr/bin/git`). To fix this problem just run the Xcode and "Accept" license conditions and try again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On Mojave

The binary is in

```
/usr/bin/git
```

The related scripts are here

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git
```