# Git won't upgrade

Tags: git

I'm trying to update to the newest version of Git on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5.  I've downloaded the newest version from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/ multiple times. I've started and restarted terminal, and no matter what "git --version" returns "1.7.9.6" even though the newest version is 1.8.5.2. "which git" returns "/usr/bin/git". Is it being installed in the wrong spot? If so, how can I specify it to install somewhere else?

Comment: Slightly off topic: I recommend to use homebrew to manage external libraries and tools (like git): http://brew.sh/.

Comment: issue `/usr/bin/git --version`, and then `echo $PATH`m and provide the output

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: What do you get when you run `which git` it should return with - `/usr/local/git/bin/git`. If the path is different and not in `/usr` you have a local install of git and that should be removed from `$PATH`

Comment: @majioa Here is the output:   /Users/NormalUse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/bin:/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: @AnthonyMyers and output `/usr/bin/git --version`? So fix your path it should looks like: `/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/bin:/Users/NormalUse/.rvm‌​/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin‌​:/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/‌​bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

The OSX installer puts everything into `/usr/local/git`, so you need to make sure `/usr/local/git/bin` is on your path.

You may want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725389/how-to-get-started-with-git-on-mac/4725627#4725627) as well.  It has some more details about installing properly on OSX.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still very new to this, so I'm trying to figure out how to change the path. I will head over to this link now.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was looking for exactly what order my path needed to be in. I opened my bash profile, and added: PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH to it. Then reinstalled latest version of Git. Opened a new Terminal window, and now we are good to go!