# Does Xcode 4 install git?

Tags: xcode, git, macos, xcode4

I bought a new MacBook Pro and installed the applications list below in order. On my old MacBook, also running OS X 10.6.6, I didn't have `/usr/bin/git`, however, on the new MacBook Pro, I do. The only differences that I can think of between the two systems are:

1. New MacBook Pro has Xcode 4 vs. Xcode 3 on old MacBook
2. New MacBook Pro installed git using homebrew vs. old MacBook installed [git-osx-installer][]

Homebrew installed git 1.7.4.1 into `/usr/local/Cellar/git` and symlinked it into `/usr/local/bin`. This leads me to believe that Xcode 4 installed `git` 1.7.3.4 into `/usr/bin`. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

If Xcode 4 didn't install git 1.7.3.4 into `/usr/bin`, any thoughts what program did?

### Applications Installed in Order

- First boot
- Ran Apple's Software Update
- Ran Bootcamp to create 48GB NTFS partition for Windows 7
- Installed iWork '09 and ran software update to install iWork Update 5
- Installed TextExpander 3.2.4
- Installed Dropbox 1.0.20
- Installed 1Password 3.5.9
- Installed Alfred 0.8.2 (107)
- Installed Adium 1.4.1
- Started installation of Xcode4 via App Store
- Installed Caffeine 1.1.1 via App Store
- Installed Kindle via App Store
- Completed installation of Xcode 4 via App Store
- Installed Homebrew using the following command:
  `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSLk https://gist.github.com/raw/323731/install_homebrew.rb)"`
- Installed git using `brew install git`
- Installed MacVim using `brew install macvim`

### Update: Package Receipt Info

I ran `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/git` and the following info was displayed. This appears to incriminate Xcode 4.

```
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/git

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.GitLeo
pkg-version: 4.0.0.9000000000.1.1248867338
install-time: 1300459157
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
```

### Why It's a Problem that Xcode 4 Installs git

By default, the path `/usr/local/bin` is after `/usr/bin` (see the file `/etc/paths`). This means that git 1.7.3.4 is used instead of 1.7.4.1 that Homebrew installed.

Comment: You can set a custom path in your .bashrc or .bash_profile script too: https://github.com/adamv/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc#L14

Comment: @Adam Vandenberg: Yes, I've customized the path in `~/.bash_profile`. Just seems weird to add `/usr/local/bin` to the path via `~/.bash_profile` when `/usr/libexec/path_helper` adds `/usr/local/bin` to the path by default. See SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5364614/95592

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it does.  I just finished the Xcode 4 install.  git was previously installed to /usr/local/git.

I am new to OS X, and can only suggest swapping the order of those directories in /etc/paths.

Not sure what else would/might work.

Answer (score 10):

Under Preferences, Downloads there was an option for Command Line Tools. I installed that and it worked well.

Answer (score 6):

I just looked into this and found git in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` after installing Xcode from the App Store on 10.7.4.  Adding that directory to my `PATH` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: This is the new correct answer. It happens because Apple deleted the special /Developer path in order to treat Xcode more like an 'app'. Do we have any reason why the install didn't add `/Apps/Xcode.../usr/bin` to our `$PATH`s already?

Answer (score 2):

I had to install the command line tools.  Here's a helpful answer https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10244#issuecomment-4013781

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 installs git at /Developer/usr/bin and at /usr/bin.  Xcode 4 uses the version at /Developer/usr/bin.  I believe Xcode 4 also invokes git with a full path, so changing the path variable won't change the version of git being used by Xcode 4 itself.  Of course, if you are just using git outside of Xcode, none of this matters.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with that same problem. Since I added the new default push style to my git command several programs have been failing because they were still using some internal old version of git.

I think I gave a good temporal solution here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/72524/26545