# Is there a problem with having /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin on the path in OS X?

Tags: macos, path

By default, OS X 10.6 uses `/usr/libexec/path_helper` to add the following paths listed in the file `/etc/paths`:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

This means that `/usr/bin` comes before `/usr/local/bin` on the path. This results in the version of [git installed by Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5364340/95592) in `/usr/bin` to be called instead of the version installed by Homebrew into `/usr/local/bin`.

Which leads me to my question, is there a problem with having `/usr/local/bin` come before `/usr/bin` in the path? Is there a specific reason that Apple defaults to having `/usr/bin` come before `/usr/local/bin`?

### How to change order of `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`

Is it a problem to move `/usr/local/bin` from the bottom of the file `/etc/paths` to the top? Doing so would impact the path for more than just when I fire up Terminal, since `/usr/libexec/path_helper` could be used by other resources (I'm uncertain about this).

While redundant, it seems safer for me to add `/usr/local/bin` to the path in `~/.bash_profile`, which would mean that `/usr/local/bin` would be on the path twice.

Comment: At least as of macOS 10.13 "High Sierra", this has changed so that `/usr/local/bin` is at the top.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, and no. They're just weird ... local by definition should override.

Comment: Any idea if there is a problem with modifying `/etc/paths` file or should I just add `/usr/local/bin` to my `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Either should work fine, but I would try to stick with only changing per-user stuff so the system isn't accidentally wrecked when an incompatible local version is installed.

Comment: @MatthewRankin Edit the /etc/paths will be no problem!!! I also encounter this issue earlier, thank you for this question. : )

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with same problem, and found the link below from googling.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3588837?start=0&tstart=0

They said that modifying */etc/paths* is not a good idea for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I found all the above useful, especially [@Ohgyun Ahn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889337/1856804) warning. So I suggest a compromise, which I just implemented:

Edit `/etc/paths` or `/private/etc/paths` (as it is in OS X 10.8) and *override git alone*. That escapes any security implications (unrelated to git, anyway) while implementing the up-to-date git for use by all programs that actually check the system-wide path.

1. Create a new directory to be used in the override, for example `/usr/local/git-override/`
2. Make new symlinks from git-override to homebrew's git programs. Just remake the git symlinks from `/usr/local/bin`.
3. add `/usr/local/git-override` to the top of `(/private)/etc/paths`.

Hope that's helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to add that if you want to keep your PATH clean (no duplicate entries), you can add the following to your .bash_profile to achieve the desired effect:

```
# remove /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin
export PATH=`echo ":$PATH:" | sed -e "s#:/usr/local/bin:#:#g" -e "s/^://" -e "s/:$//"`
export PATH=`echo ":$PATH:" | sed -e "s#:/usr/bin:#:#g" -e "s/^://" -e "s/:$//"`
# add /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin in that order
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

I learned that little trick from http://ntk.me/2013/05/04/path-environment-variable/

Edit: Very important! Don't get the order that those are removed wrong! If you do, `sed` won't work and you'll be left with `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:` as your PATH!

It's also worth noting that the others suggesting that this could introduce some security problems are correct. Please be sure to understand the risks involved!

Answer (score 1):

Since modifying the order of `/etc/paths` seams to be discouraged for system stability and security ... here my solution which is based on the answer of @vmrob

```
read PATH < <(echo "$PATH" | sed  \
    -e 's/^/:/' -e 's/$/:/'       \
    -e 's_:/usr/local/bin:_:_g'   \
    -e 's_:/usr/local/sbin:_:_g'  \
    -e "s_:/usr/bin:/bin:_:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:_"        \
    -e "s_:/usr/sbin:/sbin:_:$HOME/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:_"  \
    -e 's/^://' -e 's/:$//')
export PATH
```