# Git update (Homebrew install)

Tags: git, homebrew

I have installed GIT 1.7.7.1 via homebrew and had to do a

```
sudo brew link git
```

to link git to

```
/usr/local/bin
```

When I run git --version in terminal I get an older version of Git (1.7.5.6)

Is it possible to link to the new version instead?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364614/is-there-a-problem-with-having-usr-local-bin-before-usr-bin-on-the-path-in-os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `/usr/bin` go before `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH` and hence take precedence. I suggest to change order of paths in `$PATH`.

(Also you may try to define alias: `alias git=/usr/local/bin/git`)

Comment: this is my path, export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/yannick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/yannick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/yannick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/yannick/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: and this is my path, but I sill get the older git version

Comment: Actually it works when I reload the ~/.profile. But when I restart terminal I have to reload the path manually again. Is ~/.profile not the right place where to put $PATH?

Comment: @yannick-schall What shell do you use? If it's a `bash` then I suggest to set `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc`. For Zsh put it in `~/.zshrc`

Comment: I use Bash, I've added everything to my ~/.bash_profile and it works. Is there a big difference between the two? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that worked for me.

I found this related post to be very helpful. Instead of changing the $PATH variable, it just has you simply edit your /etc/paths file.
https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are/533708#533708

1. Open Terminal on your Mac
2. Type the command: sudo nano /etc/paths
3. Enter your password if you're asked for it
4. You will see a list of paths. Edit the list them so that */usr/local/bin* path is entered above the */usr/bin* path
5. Save step 1 - <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
6. Save step 2 - <kbd>Y</kbd>
7. Restart Terminal

Here's what mine looks like after I did that:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Credit to @jrwren & @jthomas over at StackOverflow for their answers.

Comment: Upvoted it is helpful for me. Future reader can follow [Upgrading to Git 2.0](http://rayhightower.com/blog/2014/05/30/upgrading-to-git-2-dot-0/) link as well.