# Git stopped working in Xcode 4 after migration

Tags: git, migration, xcode4

We just got new iMacs at the office, so I migrated everything from my old mac using Migration Assistant.

However git wasn't included in the migration (why?) and Xcode's git support seems to have vanished as well. Reinstalling git wasn't a problem, but Xcode still doesn't recognize git repositories.

Does anyone know why and can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode expects git to be in `/usr/bin` and you may not have installed you Git in that location.

I have a fix [here](https://gist.github.com/774277)

Comment: I just reinstalled Xcode, but yes, that seems to be the problem. Apparently, Xcode installs git and that's what solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364340/does-xcode-4-install-git

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to reinstall Xcode, if you have "Install Xcode" icon in your application folder. Xcode installs git and everything should be fine.

Comment: I suppose that's true if you've installed Xcode through App Store.

Comment: It's one of the installation options - IIRC the Command Line Tools options.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue from a Snow Leopard -> New Computer migration. One of my xcodes is installed via the app store and the other is from the ADC portal. I didn't want to wait a million hours to download the xcode installer, so I just installed git.

I used the one-click-installation (I used the 64-bit SL package) at this link and everything works fine now:

http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3