# upgrade Git on Mac

Tags: macos, git, environment-variables

I have previously installed Git(1.9.3) and I want to upgrade it to the latest version(2.0.1). I uninstalled the previous install by running the uninstall.sh first and then git.pkg. However, when I run `git --version`, it still shows me `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`.

So I did this:

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git

$ echo $PATH
...:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Obviouslly, Git in /usr/local/git/bin is the latest version I want.

So how can I remove the path of the older version and tell Mac OSX where to find the right version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution would simply to change the order in your `$PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH
source ~/.bash_profile
```

As suggested in [git: command not found (on OS X 10.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835837/6309) and [Locate Git installation folder on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089778/6309).

In your case, you do have `/usr/local/git/bin/` in your `PATH`, but in the wrong order if you want it to be taken into account.

Answer (score 5):

XCode uses its own git version, which makes it a bit difficult to update.
These two terminal commands worked for me:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-xcode
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

This solution is taken from Heroku's recently published [seurity alert](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/24/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x) for git 1.9.3. This post includes a [download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/). These two commands are advised in that link. The .dmg download package also includes a README file with a [similar link](https://github.com/timcharper/git_osx_installer/).

Comment: For me just `sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-xcode` did the trick. The other command which creates symbolic name is not needed

Answer (score 0):

A preinstalled version of Git comes with OSX and I was using that after seeing that version has some major security issues I went ahead and downloaded the latest git from git site but even after installing, when I looked it up in the terminal with the command git --version it showed me the older one.

So I googled a bit and found out that

Those security vulnerabilities issues were addressed in the beta Xcode version as mentioned in this official statement from apple.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204147

So guys go ahead and download the beta Xcode If you find it easy to use apples git like me.

Good Luck!